# Does $e^{tx} + x = t - 1$ yield a solution/s to $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{e^{-tx} - x}{e^{-tx} + t}$?

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Problem**: Use Existence Theorem to determine if $x(t)$ implicitly defined by
>
> $$e^{tx(t)} + x(t) = t - 1 \tag{*}$$
>
> yield a solution/s to
>
> $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{e^{-tx} - x}{e^{-tx} + t} \left( = \frac{1 - xe^{tx}}{1 + te^{tx}} \right) \tag{**}$$
>
> ?

---

> **Definition**: Let $x = x(t)$. A **solution of the first order ODE** $x' = f(t,x)$, where $f$ is defined on some domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ s.t. $D$ is open and connected, is a differentiable function $\varphi$ on some interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ s.t.
>
> 1. $(t, \varphi(t)) \in D \ \forall t \in I$
> 2. $\varphi'(t) = f(t, \varphi(t)) \ \forall t \in I$

---

> **Existence Theorem**: If $f$ is continuous on a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $(\tau, \xi) \in D$, then $\exists$ a solution $\varphi$ of $x' = f(t,x)$ defined on some interval $I$ s.t. $\tau \in I$ and $\varphi(\tau) = \xi$

---

What I tried:

The denominator vanishes when $x=0$ and $t=-1$ so I guess we can't say $D = \mathbb R^2$. How about

$$D = \{(t,x) | (t,x) \ne (-1,0) \}$$

?

Is that **open and connected**? We didn't have any topology courses, and our real analysis only covered $\mathbb R$.

If that's right, $f$ I guess is continuous on $D$.

Choose some point $(\tau, \xi) \in D$:

$(\tau, \xi) = (1,0)$

So $\exists$ a solution $\varphi$ of $x' = f$ defined on an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ s.t. $1 \in I$ and $\varphi(1) = 0$.

Is that right?

Comment: Use \left( \right) to adapt automaticaly the size of parenthesis. And what you means by something (=something else) ?

Comment: @Shadock Thanks. I know that but am usually too lazy. In the end, it always look better and clearer. hahaha.

Comment: @Shadock What do you mean by 'And what you means by something (=something else) ?' ? Are you referring to $(**)$? I am just rewriting, assuming I did it right

Comment: Oh ok i understand

Answer (score 1):

Just implicitly compute the derivative, we see
$$e^{tx(t)} + x =t-1  \implies  (x + t x' ) e^{tx} + x' =1 \implies x' ( 1+ te^{tx})= 1- xe^{tx} \implies x' = \frac{1 -xe^{tx} }{1 +te^{tx}} $$
Since the denominator is bad along $1+te^{tx}=0$, this is line we avoid for $x(t)$. By the implicit function theorem, we may always find $x(t)$ everywhere else.

Comment: So what are the $D$, $I$ ($I$'s) and $\varphi$ ($\varphi$'s) exactly?

Comment: you can't always compute the explicit function. You just know it'll exists. given an initial data point $(t_0,x_0)$, you know that the solution exists on $ I = ( t_0 - \delta , t_0 + \delta ) $ and $D = ( x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$ provided they don't cross the mentioned line above.

Comment: Jeb, you mean there's only one solution? I think there are two solutions.

Comment: Oh shoot sorry for the confusion, Jeb. I am supposed to prove or disprove existence of solutions not solve for any. Edited question. Gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

$$x' = \frac{1 - xe^{tx} }{1 + te^{tx}}$$
$$x' + te^{tx}x'+xe^{tx} -1=0$$
$$\left(x+e^{tx}-t \right)'=0$$
$$x+e^{tx}-t = c$$
This is the inplicit form of all the solutions.

The proposed solution $e^{tx}+x=t-1$ is one of them (particular case $c=-1$ ).

NOTE :

An explicit form of the solutions can be derrived, thanks to the Lambert's W function.

$$e^{tx}=-x+t+c$$
$$ (-x+t+c)e^{-tx}=1$$
$$ (-tx+t^2+ct)e^{-tx}=t$$
$$ (-tx+t^2+ct)e^{-tx+t^2-ct}=te^{t^2-ct}$$
with $W= (-tx+t^2+ct)$ and $X=te^{t^2-ct}$ then  $W e^W=X$ where $W=W(X)$
$$-tx+t^2+ct=W\left(te^{t^2-ct}\right)$$
$$x=t+c-\frac{1}{t}W\left(te^{t^2-ct}\right)$$
According to the properties of the Lambert W function, $W(X)$ returns one value if $X>0$, or two values if $-\frac{1}{e}<X<0$ and no real value if $X<-\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: Oh shoot sorry for the confusion, JJacquelin. I am supposed to prove or disprove existence of solutions not solve for any. Edited question. Gave you an upvote.

Comment: On my viewpoint, there is no confusion at all. Solving the ODE is a very good method to prove or disaprove the existence of solutions. Moreover, it gives precisely in what domains the solution exists or not and if they are on multiple forms or not. It was not specified in the wording of the question that this method was excluded. It doesn't matter because my answer was also to show a method for complete solving to people interested on this subject.

Comment: Ummmmm we're supposed to use the theorem............

Comment: @BCLC : I agree that my way to answer is not what was expected : The final question was "Is that right?" about the work you have done.

Comment: And so now....?